# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. in server while working in local c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the datepicker:

```
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.16/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    $(function () {
        $("[id$=txtExpDate]").datepicker({

            //dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy',
          //  dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
            //buttonImageOnly: true,
            //buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif'
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $("[id$=txtManDate]").datepicker({

            //dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy',
          //  dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
            //buttonImageOnly: true,
            //buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the code for convert:

```
DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtManDate.Text);

DateTime dt3 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtExpDate.Text);
```

The server database i am using for insert value..this working very well in local code...but not working in server.

Error is:

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

What should  i do??

I have already tried:

```
var manDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtManDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(manDate);

var expDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtExpDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt3 = Convert.ToDateTime(expDate);
```

But still the same error..any suggestion??

Comment: What is the format of date in `txtManDate.Text`

Comment: MM/dd/yyyy is the format..any suggestion??

Comment: What is the value of string in `txtManDate.Text` ?

Comment: I am using server mssql..working very well..but problems in server??

Comment: The datepicker suggests that you use `"MM-dd-yy"`

Comment: 01/24/2017..this is the format..mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: what should i do??

Comment: Try to parse it as like `DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(txtManDate.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`, without the format string.

Comment: already used..but not working..if you have any suggestion can you tell me??

Comment: If you are sure that your string that is in txtManDate.Text equals `01/24/2017` then the exact parse without format string and invariant culture, should work, you should check your input string.

Comment: Also you can try to run this line `DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse("01/24/2017", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` on your machine just to test if invariant culture is ok, if no errors then your input string is wrong, you need to debug

Comment: output the input string on error, we can only provide wild guesses without seeing the string

Answer (score 0):

Client and server culture? If server is en and client it you must set your date in yyyy-MM-dd